# Function overload with subclass in swift

Tags: swift, swift3

I have this code:

```
class A {

}

class B : A {

}

class Example {

    func action(_ param : A) -> String {
        return "A"
    }

    func action(_ param : B) -> String {
        return "B"
    }

    func test() -> String {
        let t : A = B()

        return self.action(t) // returns A
    }

}
```

I'm passing a B object but casted as A, therefore it calls `action(_ param : A)` when I want it to call the `action(_ param : B)` function.

Is it possible to do that without using `is`/`as!`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Polymorphism is exactly how you get rid of the `if` and `is` that you so dread. That, in fact, is what polymorphism *is*. The problem is that you use the *word* "polymorphic" but you forgot to *use* polymorphism. In effect, there is *no* polymorphism in your code. Polymorphism means that each class or subclass acts *for itself*. Thus:

```
class A {
    func who() -> String {return "A"}
}

class B : A {
    override func who() -> String {return "B"}
}

class Example {
    func action(_ param : A) -> String {
        return param.who()
    }
    func test() -> String {
        let t : A = B()
        return self.action(t) // returns B
    }
}
```

The alternative would be to say for example

```
return String(describing:type(of:param))
```

but I assume that you know that and that you count that as the same as saying `is` and `as`.

Comment: should have used a different word then, or use quotes because I knew it was not exactly polymorphism. But I want a function to act differently depending on the class it's given. I can just use `is` but i wanted to know if there was a better way :)

Comment: Well, if you throw away polymorphism, then no, there is no better way; that is what testing types (`is`) and casting (`as`) is _for_.

Comment: The alternative would be to say e.g. `return String(describing:type(of:param))`

Comment: How would you call a "two functions with same name but different argument type, one being a subclass of the other one" so I can change the question's title appropriately then?

The example code is just a playground, my goal is not to return the name of the class ;)

Comment: I figured that it wasn't your real code. But in this case you are the one who deliberately typed a B as an A and then complained that your A version of the function was called. That is like hitting yourself in the face and complaining that your face is being hit. :) What I suggest is that you forget about this question and start over, asking about what you _really_ want to do.

Comment: I am just asking if there is a better way than using `is`, I don't have to start over anything, my code is working very well using `is` x) Don't worry I'm fine :D Thank you for your help